# Re rename batch: how to change part of filenames in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

let's say I have main folder with many subfolders and inside them there are excel files. I want to change a certain part of filenames in all subfolders. I tried my best, but I am a new to Batch and I have no idea how to solve it.
For example:
- present version file123 2016.xlsx 
- expected version file123 2017.xlsx

My attempt:

```
@echo off
cd C:\example\

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set var1=2016
    Set var2=2017
    for /r %%G in (*.xlsx) do (
    set "filename=%%G"
    ren "!filename!" "!filename:%var1%=%var2%!"
)
```

Let me know if you've got any solution! Thx! :)

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING HERE?

Comment: What do you mean? I am new here, maybe I don't stick to the rules? It's my first post, did i make a mistake i my post?

Comment: There is no need to write a post title with caps lock on. If anything, you'll get better responses without it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trailing space in your line `Set var1=2016`. Batch is very picky about spaces, so the space is part of the variable.  To avoid this, use the following syntax:

```
set "var1=2016"
```

Another error:

`ren /?` says: `ren [drive:][path]filename1 filename2`
You can't give a path for the destination name.

Try this:

```
for /r %%G in (*.xlsx) do (
    set "filename=%%~nxG"
    ren "%%G" "!filename:%var1%=%var2%!"
)
```

`%%~nxG` gives you **n**ame and e**x**tension only.

Comment: I fixed it, but my code still doesn't work properly. I don't know where the error is, but thanks for your useful comment!

Comment: please define "doesn't work properly". Remove `@echo off` to see any errormessages.

Comment: This first code below works as I expect, 
cd C:\Example\
for %%f in (*%.xslx%) do (
    set "filename=%%f"
    ren "!filename!" "!filename:%var1%=%var2%!"
)
pause >nul

Here the problem occurs, I don't know how to go through all subfolders and find files in order to make a rename. The error is Syntax error.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var1=2019
set var2=2016
cd C:\Example\
for /r /d %%G in (*%.xslx%) do (
    set "filename=%%G"
    ren "!filename!" "!filename:%var1%=%var2%!"
)
pause >nul